# Excel VBA - Check if file exists using Wildcard and open the file

Tags: excel, vba

I wish to check whether a file exist in a folder on my computer. I have below, which can see if a **specific** file exists:

```
Function FileExists(sFile As String)
    sPath = "M:\User\" & sFile & ".xlsm"
    FileExists = Dir(sPath) <> ""
End Function
```

However, my files are named like: `Filename - Version xx.xlsm` and is updated regularly. Please note that there will only be **one** file in the folder, but the filename can vary.

How can I search in the folder using wildcard:

`Filename - Version % %` and then, if it find any file, open the file afterwards?

Comment: `& sFile & "*" & ".xlsm"`? or `& sFile & "*.xlsm"`

Comment: Dir doesn't work with filenames having unicode characters in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to Open the file inside of the `FileExists` function.  However, I would not recommend doing this.  The function should do exactly what the name implies and nothing more.

Another option is restructure your code a little bit:

```
Private Sub OpenFile()
   Dim FileName As String

   FileName = GetFile("Filename - Version*")

   If FileName <> "" Then
      'open FileName as needed
   End If
End Sub

Private Function GetFile(sFile As String) As String
    sPath = "M:\User\" & sFile & ".xlsm"
    GetFile = Dir(sPath)
End Function
```